# Emploi de "l'Alpha et l'Oméga"

Tags: grec, religion

La locution grecque *l'alpha et l'oméga* a-t-elle toujours une allusion biblique ? Peut-on l'employer couramment pour signifier le début et la fin ainsi que la totalité ? Exemple :

> Un cosmologue réfléchira à l'alpha et à l'oméga de l'univers.
>
> Le goût est la qualité fondamentale qui résume toutes les autres qualités. C’est l'alpha et l'oméga de l’intelligence.
>
> Qu'elle constitue l'alpha et l'oméga de toute politique de paix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Ça n'est pas nécessairement religieux. Ça signifie 'le début et la fin', et par ext. 'tout'.
- Comme le montrent vos exemples, il s'agit de "l'alpha et l'oméga" et non de "alpha et oméga".
- On dit généralement "X est l'alpha et l'oméga de Y" ("C'est l'alpha et l'oméga de l'intelligence." marche bien). C'est assez figé comme emploi : "réfléchir à l'alpha et [à] l'oméga" fait bizarre.